# passing value via navigateByUrl with navigationExtras empty

Tags: angular, angular-router

Hi i have a function that navigate to another page and passing a id to another component but it return nothing to the other component. Not sure what i am doing wrong could someone point me in the right direction.

```
gotoConsulting(questionId: number): void {   

   let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
      queryParams: { 'origine': questionId.toString },
      fragment: 'anchor'
   };
  console.log("idquestion"  + questionId);
    this._router.navigateByUrl('/consulting',navigationExtras);
}
```

here the component that get redirect but always return in the view None

```
export class PageConsulting implements OnInit {

  origine: Observable<string>;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.origine = this.route
      .queryParamMap
      .map(params => params.get('origine') || 'None');
  }


}
```

Comment: How you think that it doesn't return anything?

Comment: If you remove || 'None' does it return an error or what you are trying to get?

Comment: @DarkVision Did you ever get to pass values via navigateByUrl ?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25658

Answer (score 0):

Using the navigate() function appears to cause issues with routes that use the `!#` prefix in Angular

Answer (score -1):

You should use `this.router.navigate([redirect], navigationExtras);` instead of `navigateByUrl`.

Only navigate have the parameter navigationExtras.

You can refer to **angular website below**:

https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.